# Splash Screen does not appear in android application

Tags: android, splash-screen

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    Intent LoginActivity = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(LoginActivity);
    finish();
}
```

}

with `activity_splash_screen` is layout of splash screen. My app has displayed white screen instead of my splash-image.

when I do not set the next action `LoginActivity` my splash-image comes back!

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    // Intent LoginActivity = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
    // startActivity(LoginActivity);
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `Thread.sleep()` on your main thread.
Try this instead:

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent LoginActivity = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(LoginActivity);
            finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: It seems that my app has crashed, then (after 5s) opened login screen! the splash-image is still disappear!

Comment: @ĐôngNguyễnTrọng Remove this: `try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }`

Comment: I want to set splash-screen theme over certain duration (which I customize) when the app starting running time. In login activity, there is another theme!